# I'm getting the first response an empty list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm getting data from API like this:

```
const [software, setSoftware] = useState([]);

const id = match.params.id;

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/${id}/`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setSoftware(data)
      })
}, [id]);
```

First response is an empty list, but the next response is my list from API. I tried to use useEffect because setSoftwares is asynchronous, but it didn't help.
So how can I get only my list?

Comment: Couldnt understand your question, but I think you must have logged the state right after setting it causing it to show the initial empty array.

Comment: May be what you need (intented to ask) is, Kind of fallback component ( that displays loading message ) until your API responds back.
if that is the case, have one more state variable "loading" defaults to true. and mark it fales after API completes. Toggle your list and loading component based on the valu of "loading" variable

Comment: @Karthikeyan It helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending incorrect `id` for the first time, try to `console.log(id)` it and check-in the console if `id` is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `id` is valid